# auth.user.none and <QuerySet []> in ManyToManyField rendering

Tags: python, django

I try to display numbers of Users who liked some image on my website written in Django. 
The Image model looks like this below:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    (***)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                        related_name='images_liked',
                        blank=True)
```

When I use in my template:

> {{image.users_like.all}}

I get :

**QuerySet []**,

when I use in templates

> {{image.users_like}}

I get

**auth.User.None**.

It's weird because in my admin page I have information that someone liked this photo.

Below my view function:

```
def image_detail(request, id, slug):
    image = get_object_or_404(Image, id=id, slug=slug)
    return render(request,
              'images/image/detail.html',
              {'section': 'images',
              'image': image})
```

**EDIT**

My admin page, in Users like section display usernames of user who already liked the photo. PrtSc below:
[image: photyo]

**FULL BLOCK**

```
<h1>{{ image.title }}</h1>
`<p>{{image.users_like.all}}</p>
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail image.image "300" as im %}
    <a href="{{ image.image.url }}">
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" class="image-detail">
    </a>
{% endthumbnail %}
{% with total_likes=image.users_like.count users_like=image.users_like.all %}
    <div class="image-info">
            <div>
                <span class="count">
                    <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
                    like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
                </span>
                <a href="#" data-id="{{ image.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in users_like %}un{% endif %}like" class="like button">
                    {% if request.user not in users_like %}
                        Like
                    {% else %}
                        Unlike
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
            </div>
        {{ image.description|linebreaks }}
    </div>

    <div class="image-likes">
        {% for user in image.users_like.all %}
            <div>
                <img src="{{ user.profile.photo.url }}">
                <p>{{ user.first_name }}</p>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            Nobody likes this image yet.
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Please show your template. `image.users_like.all` is correct, but you should loop through the elements (`{% for user in image.users_like.all %}`) and then do something for each `user`. But if you see **QuerySet[]** it really means that no user liked this image so I'd like to know how you see in your admin page that "someone liked this photo".

Comment: do you want to show the count ?

Comment: I’d like to display number of total likes and user.profile.photo’s of people who liked image. But when i try get this values by several ways (i.e. {{image.users_like.all}}, {{image.users_like.count}} or {{image.users_like.all | length}} ), Django says something  like „QuerySet is empty”. On another hand my admin page display informations about users who liked image already.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here - the admin screenshot you have included shows the list of available users but *none of them have been selected* which means the m2m relationship is empty - if any of those users had liked the image then they would be selected (highlighted) in the multi-select field. You need to select (Ctrl + click to select multiple) users and save for them to be associated with the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in the comments above. QuerySet was empty when called. After adding users to image.users_like the problem disappeared. Thank you solarissmoke.